# CanCanCan ability to create Invite resource if User can manage Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan

I have the following Group ability defined:

```
# Group abilities
can :manage, Group do |group|
  user.in_group?(group, as: :owner)
end
```

what I would like for the Invite is something like:

```
can :manage, Invite do |invite|
  can?(:manage, invite.group)
end
```

In other words, I would like to support users having the ability to create Invites for a group they are an owner of. Since groups can have multiple owners (via a GroupMemberships object), I can't use the simple association hash rules. I also can't use a block because there isn't an instance of `@invite` in `InvitesController#create`.

How would you go about writing an ability rule for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
can :manage, Invite, group: { group_memberships: { user: user, membership_type: 'owner' } }
```

is the ability that ended up working for the create action with the following CanCanCan hooks in the controller:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :group
  authorize_resource :invite, through: :group
```

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood you and the tiny amount of code provided correctly you can do it by:

```
can :manage, Invite do |invite|
  user.in_group?(invite.group, as: :owner)
end
```

Comment: yea, my hope was to keep the ability file DRY and not duplicate the authorization logic for the invite and instead just say, "If they can manage the group they're inviting a user to, then they're allowed to create an invite"

Comment: yea the other issue is that `user.in_group?(invite.group, as: :owner)` won't work since there isn't an `@invite` variable available in the `:create` action. I believe CanCanCan uses the class name instead.

Comment: You'll probably have to do the authorizations call manually instead of using `load_and_authorize_resource`. As previously explained CanCanCan gets ugly real fast when you get to more complex scenarios.

Comment: So you would have to call `can?(:manage, @group)` and then create the new instance.